# On clicking the chat option from a secure URL of Android stack exchange it migrates me to the generalized chat page

Tags: support, bug, chat

Why does clicking on Chat at the bottom takes me to  the general chat of stack exchange instead of Android chat page group which consist of the Android related chat.
[image: This is the screen shot for the secure android stack exchange]

Upon clicking the chat option in the bottom of the  page from a secure URL gives me the below page.(i.e.https://)

[image: This is the output on clicking the chat from the secure android website]

The above screen shot shows that when clicking the chat option it loads the page of the generalized chat page containing the chat groups for all the stack exchange sites which in the end is also a non-secure URL.

The below image is the output of clicking the chat option from a non secure URL(i.e.http://)
[image: the normal output of the android chat which should appear from a secure URL also]

Although the secure URL loads fine without any errors of Certification then why is it loading the generalized chat page instead of the Specific chat page.

Browser-Internet Explorer v11